# German-Chinese online dictionary

Tags: resources, dictionary

Is there any online dictionary German-Chinese and vice versa that allows user participation?

I know of

- handedict.de, dormant since 2011, forums down, but allows downloading a wordfile
- dict.leo.org, working, but crummy participation: must ask in forum to have a word added, does not allow downloading a wordfile
- wiktionary, working, but inconvenient lookup, may compile wordfile from dump inconviently

No user participation in

- chinesisch-lernen.org
- chinalink.de

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly a dictionary, but if you have individual words you need to find the meaning of quickly, you may want to try this:

http://translate.reference.com/

I have used Chinese-English, and occasionally other languages as well. As with many digital translation devices, the result isn't always ideal, but you can probably use this as an additional reference.

A word of caution: it does not do idioms well.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) allows some degree of user participation. Strictly speaking it's not exactly a dictionary, but you can use it as one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: http://www.godic.net/
(hope it helps)